# $ B=\left\{(\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_n)\in \mathbb{R^n}\colon |\beta_1|+|\beta_2|+\dots+|\beta_n|=1\right\} $ is closed & bounded

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

How can I show that
$$
B=\left\{(\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_n)\in \mathbb{R^n}\colon |\beta_1|+|\beta_2|+\dots+|\beta_n|=1\right\}
$$
is closed and bounded?

Comment: if this is a question that came up in a course, the answer really depends on what machinery you're allowed to use at that point of the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function $| \beta_1 | + |\beta_2| + ... + |\beta_n|$ is a continuous function, so the pre-image of a closed set, in this case the singleton $1$ is a closed set. Therefore the set $B$ is closed.

It is bounded, because $\|(\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_n)\| > 1$ implies that $|\beta_1| + |\beta_2| + ... + |\beta_n|$ > 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** consider the continuous function

$$
f \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R, f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = |x_1|+\cdots +|x_n|
$$